# Catch keypress in angularjs service - element independent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do what the title says, but still I cannot get any callback function called.
I want to keep the key detection in the service and reflect the key pressing using the '`this.keyPressed`' member. The code is pretty explicit about it. I am not interested in watching for the event in the controller, I am coming from that. I want to create a reusable service so I can use it in other controllers, without repeating code.
I want to be able to catch a keypress regardless which html element has the focus.

Code:

```
    'use strict';

app.service(
    'shiftKeyService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

        var that = this;

        this.keyPressed = false;
        this.cleanUp = CleanUpService;


        var hUpCleaner = $rootScope.$on("keyup", HandlerUp);
        var hDownCleaner = $rootScope.$on("keydown", HandlerDown);

        $rootScope.$on('keypress', function (e, a, key) {
            alert("gotcha");
        })

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        function CleanUpService() {
            hDownCleaner();
            hDownCleaner();
        }

        function HandlerUp(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 16) {
                that.keyPressed = false;
            }
        }

        function HandlerDown(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 16) {
                that.keyPressed = true;
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my final working service for this:

```
(function (ng, app) {
    'use strict';

    app.service(
        'shiftKeyService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

            var that = this;
            var $doc = angular.element(document);

            this.keyPressed = false;
            this.cleanUp = CleanUpService;


            $doc.on("keyup", HandlerUp);
            $doc.on("keydown", HandlerDown);

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            function CleanUpService() {
                $doc.off("keyup", HandlerUp);
                $doc.off("keydown", HandlerDown);
            }

            function HandlerUp(e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 16) {
                    that.keyPressed = false;
                }
            }

            function HandlerDown(e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 16) {
                    that.keyPressed = true;
                }
            }
        }]);

})(angular, myApp);
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
(function (ng, app) {

    "use strict";

    app.controller(
        "production.DocumentsController",
        ['$scope', 'shiftKeyService',
        function ($scope, shiftKeyService) {

            //shiftKeyService.keyPressed is your weapon of choice, it's updated on every keyDown/keyUp.

            //and if you no longer require it :
            $scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
                shiftKeyService.CleanUp();
            });          
        }]);
})(angular, myApp);
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE :

You could create a directive like this:

```
app.directive("shiftDirective",function(){
    return{
         link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
             elem.on('keypress', function(){
                 // keypress stuff
             }),
             elem.on('keyup', function() {
                 // keyup stuff
             }),
             elem.on('keydown', function() {
                 // keydown stuff
             })
         }
    }
})
```

And then you can use this directive anywhere you want without recoding it, just by adding it to other directives like this:

```
<div shift-directive></div>
<input shift-directive type="text" />
```

OLD VERSION:

You can use one of the following directives on your element that you wish to listen for key events (don't forget that element must be inside your required controller scope):

```
ng-keypress="myEventHandler($event)"
ng-keyup="myEventHandler($event)"
ng-keydown="myEventHandler($event)"
```

And in your controller, define the function that will be called when the user triggers the event:

```
$scope.myEventHandler = function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13)
    alert('Key 13 pressed');
}
```

Comment: I want to do this from angular js code .. no event handler in the view .. I don't want the view to know about this.

Comment: How do you listen for key events in the rootScope, in a service/provider ?

Comment: As I understand your post, you don't want to rewrite your methods for every directive where you're going to need your key binding.
But a key binding must be linked to a directive, event if it's in the body.
The best solution I think would be to create a custom directives with all your methods.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom directive and u can call manually keypress event

```
app.directive("myDirective",function(){
    return{
         link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
            elem.on('keypress', function(){
            // do some thing here 
          } 
        }
     }
})
```

Comment: I don't want to limit this to a single html element, I have a working version, in which I capture the keypress 'view wide', but I want to put that in a reusable container.

Comment: directives are reusable components across the application..u can make a directive

Comment: ng-keypress this is the same thing